# Convert recursive function to view

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, tree, common-table-expression

I'm trying to convert a function in Postgres into a `select` query which I intend to use as a view. The reason is that I'd like to access it from a client via a `select` query with a `where` clause instead of using a parameter as with the function.
The table represents a tree (and adjacency list) and is defined as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE tree (
  id serial primary key,
  parent_id int references tree(id)
);

INSERT INTO tree (id, parent_id) VALUES
  (1,null)
, (2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (5,3)
, (6,5), (7,6), (8,4), (9,8)
, (10,9), (11,9), (12,7)
, (13,12), (14,12), (15,11)
, (16,15), (17,16), (18,14)
, (19,13), (20,19), (21,20);

SELECT setval ('tree_id_seq', 21); -- reset sequence

-- This produces a tree like:
--                                                   +-- <10>
--                                                  /
--                         +-- <4> -- <8> --- <9> -+- <11> --- <15> --- <16> --- <17>
--                        /                                        
--  <1> --- <2> --- <3> -+                                       
--                        \                                  
--                         +-- <5> --- <6> --- <7> --- <12> -+- <14> --- <18>
--                                                            \               
--                                                             \            
--                                                              \                
--                                                               \                   
--                                                                +-- <13> --- <19> --- <20> --- <21>
--
```

To get a path from any node in the tree to the root in order, I use this function:

```
create or replace function _tree(rev int)
  returns table(id int, parent_id int, depth int) as $$
declare
  sql text;
begin
  sql = 'WITH RECURSIVE tree_list(id, parent_id, depth) AS (
          SELECT id, parent_id, 1 FROM tree  WHERE id = ' || rev || 
          'UNION 
           SELECT p.id, p.parent_id, r.depth + 1
           FROM tree p, tree_list r
           WHERE p.id = r.parent_id
         )
         SELECT id, parent_id, depth FROM tree_list order by id;';
  return query execute sql;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

A query would look like `select * from _tree(15)`. The question is how would I go about converting this function into a view, so I could call `select * from tree where id <= 15`. Also, would a view be executed at the same speed as the function (i.e. would the where clause be considered *while* executing the query)?

Comment: Please clarify what the result of `select * from tree where id <= 15` should look like. And *always* declare the version of PostgreSQL you use.

Comment: The path from <15> to <1> which is a record with id = 15, 11, 9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1. Note that this is just an example. It should work equally well with any other number.

Comment: One record? The (currently) accepted answer returns multiple records. It also does nothing a `select * from _tree(15)` couldn't do, just *extremely* ineffective as it calls the function for every single column - effectively correlated subqueries. This makes no sense at all.

Comment: No, multiple records - one record for each id. You're right, it does the same as a function. I'd like to assign triggers which isn't quite possible when using a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_tree AS
SELECT tr.id as start,
       (_tree(tr.id)).id, 
       (_tree(tr.id)).parent_id, 
       (_tree(tr.id)).depth
FROM tree tr;
```

It is a view of paths from all nodes the to root.

Then use something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM v_tree
WHERE start = 15;
```

To get desired path.

It works for me on your example data, but i haven't tested it for performance.

Updated query to call `_tree` only once :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_tree AS
SELECT t_tree.start,
       (t_tree.node).id, 
       (t_tree.node).parent_id, 
       (t_tree.node).depth
FROM (SELECT tr.id as start,
            _tree(tr.id) as node
      FROM tree tr) t_tree;
```

Comment: Btw, is this as efficient as just calling the function directly?

Comment: It involves index scan for "tree" and executes "_tree" for a single row, found on index scan.

Comment: Overhead for index scan is really small, but it may call "_tree" 3 times instead of 1. (my guess - "_tree" is called 1 time. You have to test it, to be sure)

Comment: I tested it. It's called 3 times (at least that's what I see when changing the number of selected columns).

Answer (score 4):

#### Simpler function

First of all, you can **simplify** your function quite a bit. This simpler SQL function does the same:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tree(_rev int)
 RETURNS TABLE(id int, parent_id int, depth int)
 LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
WITH RECURSIVE tree_list AS (
   SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, 1 AS depth
   FROM   tree t
   WHERE  t.id = $1

   UNION ALL  -- no point using UNION
   SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, r.depth + 1
   FROM   tree_list r
   JOIN   tree t ON t.id = r.parent_id
   )
SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, t.depth
FROM   tree_list t
ORDER  BY t.id;
$func$;
```

Call:

```
select * from f_tree(15);
```

You *could* use PL/pgSQL, might be *slightly* beneficial for cashing the query plan in versions before PostgreSQL 9.2. But you voided the only theoretical benefit by using dynamic SQL without need. This makes no sense at all. Simplify to plain SQL.

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, cheaper since there cannot be dupes by design.

#### Just SQL

Obviously, you can replace this with plain SQL:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE tree_list AS (
   SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, 1 AS depth
   FROM   tree t
   WHERE  t.id = 15  -- enter parameter here

   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, r.depth + 1
   FROM   tree_list r
   JOIN   tree t ON t.id = r.parent_id
   )
SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, t.depth
FROM   tree_list t
ORDER  BY t.id;
```

Does the same.

#### VIEW

Now, the `VIEW` is a trivial matter:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_tree15 AS
WITH RECURSIVE tree_list AS (
   SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, 1 AS depth
   FROM   tree t
   WHERE  t.id <= 15   -- only detail to change

   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, r.depth + 1
   FROM   tree_list r
   JOIN   tree t ON t.id = r.parent_id
   )
SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, t.depth
FROM   tree_list t
ORDER  BY t.id;
```

The result does not make a lot of sense to me, but the question does not define anything more sensible ...

Comment: Thanks for simplifying the query. It seemed easiest to construct the query string. I have to admit that I didn't spend any though on performance.