# iterative depth of tree

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

The problematic code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(searchid INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    level INTEGER := 0;
    mid INTEGER := searchid;
BEGIN
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT id INTO mid FROM tbl1 WHERE parent_id=mid) LOOP
        level := level + 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN level;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;
```

I need to find the tree depth of an element with id `searchid`, I've written a slightly different function than above which uses `mid NOTNULL` as a condition of the while loop and it works.

However, when I try to use `EXISTS` directly in the WHILE condition **as in the code posted above**, postgresql says:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: SELECT  EXISTS(SELECT id INTO  $1  FROM tbl1 WHERE ...
```

So it does some strange transformations on my code which make it syntactically wrong.

How to fix it?

It runs on postgresql 8.3.17.

Comment: Is the expression `mid NOTNULL` or `mid NOT NULL`?  The space is important.

Comment: @GordonLinoff without space.

Comment: . . If you add the space, I think that may fix your problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Where to add the space? The code with `EXISTS` contains no `NOTNULL`.

Comment: You forgot to mention your **version of PostgreSQL**. For a programmer, that should go without saying. The best solution depends on your version.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter It runs on postgresql 8.3.17.

Comment: If you update to a more recent version, you could achieve this with a single SQL statement which is probably going to be more efficient (btzw. 8.3 is going to be de-supported very soon)

Comment: My solution requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or later. Since you failed to mention your outdated version number I assumed current software. Upgrade to a recent version or find your own solution. It should be easy enough now that I pointed out the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record:

If you were using an up-to-date version of Postgres, you could do this more efficiently with a single statement:

```
with recursive tree as (
   select id, parent, 1 as level
   from tbl1
   where id = 1
   union all
   select c.id, c.parent, p.level + 1
   from tbl1 c
     join tree p on c.parent = p.id
)
select max(level)
from tree
```

Answer (score 1):

The key mistake is that you cannot assign a variable with `SELECT INTO` inside an `EXISTS` construct. `SELECT` items inside the `EXISTS` construct are ignored.

I rewrote the function to simplify and make it more secure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_searchid int, OUT _level int)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   _level := 0;
   LOOP
      SELECT INTO _level, _searchid
                  _level + 1, t.id
      FROM   tbl1 t
      WHERE  t.parent_id = _searchid;

      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT foo(1);
```

#### Major points

- It is your responsibility to prevent the loop from being infinite.
- The `_` prefix of parameters is to avoid naming conflicts with potential columns of the used table.
- I use the special variable [`FOUND`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) that is set `TRUE` after (and only after) certain SQL statements (like `SELECT INTO`) found a row.
- Use the [`EXIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS) command to exit the loop when no row was found.
- Increment `_level` inside the `SELECT`. (Or in the loop body, it's just a tiny simplification.)
- Since PostgreSQL **9.1** you can assign to `IN` parameters, so I (ab)use `_searchid` and don't need to DECLARE any additional variables. Don't do this, if you need the original parameter value later in the function.
- The function should not be declared `IMMUTABLE`, since it accesses a table. I made it `STABLE` instead. You *can* make the function `IMMUTABLE` to "cheat" and be able to use it in index creation (for instance) - but it's on you if such an index breaks after a change in the underlying table.

#### Recursive CTE

With modern PostgreSQL you could also use a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) for the job. That's what @a_horse hinted at in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729648/iterative-depth-of-tree#comment18866745_13729648) - oh, and what he posted now as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13732632/939860).
Another example (of many on SO) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13391457/939860).

Comment: Maybe it is better to `SELECT _level + 1, t.id INTO _level, _searchid`? Your current query is really confusing. Even for me.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: Well, that's really a matter of taste. You can put the `INTO` part most anywhere in the command. I *always* put it first because that's *least confusing* IMHO. This way you can see it's `SELECT INTO` and not just `SELECT` right away - which happens to be what the OP missed to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of writing your own function you would like to use postgres extension with function that was created to present hierarchical data that is stored in a table?
It's called connectby and it is a part of tablefunc extension. How to use the function you can find [here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html)

To install extension:

```
 CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

You've got many possibilities like you can choose: key value of the row to start at, maximum depth to descend to, or zero for unlimited depth, or string to separate keys with in branch output.