# Improve query performance for union of CTE + normal select

Tags: performance, postgresql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.2

On the basis of [Convert recursive function to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391457/convert-recursive-function-to-view/), I'd like to speed up the retrieval of the path from any arbitrary node in the graph to its root by creating a snapshot of a node's parents. The idea is that the recursive tree walk is bounded by having intermediate snapshots which avoid any further recursion and hence speed up execution time. I haven't performed a load test, so I don't know how this performs beyond this simple example, but early trials already indicate some bottlenecks. I'd be happy for comments on how to speed things up/simplify queries. I'm using Postgres 9.2.2.0 (20).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS revision CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE revision (
  id serial primary key,
  parent_revision_id int references revision(id),
  username varchar(128),
  ts timestamp without time zone
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS revision_snapshot CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE revision_snapshot (
  id serial primary key,
  revision_id int,
  parent_revision_id int,
  depth int
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_revision_snapshot(_rev int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DELETE FROM revision_snapshot WHERE revision_id=$1;
INSERT INTO revision_snapshot (revision_id, parent_revision_id, depth) 
  (SELECT $1, id, depth FROM revision_tree($1));
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;


-- Recursively return path from '_rev' to root
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION revision_tree(_rev int)
 RETURNS TABLE(id int, parent_revision_id int, depth int) AS
$func$
   WITH RECURSIVE rev_list(id, parent_revision_id, depth) AS (
      SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, 1
      FROM   revision t
      WHERE  t.id = $1

      UNION ALL
      SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, r.depth + 1
      FROM   rev_list r
      JOIN   revision t ON t.id = r.parent_revision_id
   )
   SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, t.depth
   FROM   rev_list t
   ORDER  BY t.id;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;


-- Fast version of 'revision_tree' (to be). This version will return the 
-- revision tree making use of snapshots (recursively returning the path from 
-- specified revision id to last snapshot of the path to the root + the snapshot)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION revision_tree_perf(_rev int)
  RETURNS TABLE(parent_revision_id int) AS
$func$
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE graph_result ON COMMIT DROP AS
  WITH RECURSIVE rev_list(id, parent_revision_id, depth) AS (
      SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, 1
      FROM   revision t
      WHERE  t.id = $1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, r.depth + 1
      FROM   rev_list r
      JOIN   revision t ON t.id = r.parent_revision_id
      WHERE  not(t.id in (select revision_id from revision_snapshot))
   )
   SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, t.depth
   FROM   rev_list t
   ORDER  BY t.id;
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT g.parent_revision_id FROM graph_result AS g WHERE g.parent_revision_id IS NOT NULL 
   UNION
   SELECT s.parent_revision_id FROM revision_snapshot AS s WHERE 
     s.revision_id = (SELECT min(q.parent_revision_id) FROM graph_result as q) ORDER BY parent_revision_id;
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


-- Example tree
--
--                                                   +-- <10>
--                                                  /
--                         +-- <4> -- <8> --- <9> -+- <11> --- <15> --- <16> --- <17>
--                        /                                    
--  <1> --- <2> --- <3> -+                                     
--                        \                                    
--                         +-- <5> --- <6> --- <7> --- <12> -+- <14> --- <18>
--                                                            \
--                                                             \
--                                                              \
--                                                               \
--                                                                +-- <13> --- <19> --- <20> --- <21>
--


INSERT INTO revision (username, ts, parent_revision_id) VALUES
  ('someone', now(), null)   -- 1
  ,('someone', now(), 1)     -- 2
  ,('someone', now(), 2)     -- 3
  ,('someone', now(), 3)     -- 4
  ,('someone', now(), 3)     -- 5
  ,('someone', now(), 5)     -- 6
  ,('someone', now(), 6)     -- 7
  ,('someone', now(), 4)     -- 8
  ,('someone', now(), 8)     -- 9
  ,('someone', now(), 9)     -- 10
  ,('someone', now(), 9)     -- 11
  ,('someone', now(), 7)     -- 12
  ,('someone', now(), 12)    -- 13
  ,('someone', now(), 12)    -- 14
  ,('someone', now(), 11)    -- 15
  ,('someone', now(), 15)    -- 16
  ,('someone', now(), 16)    -- 17
  ,('someone', now(), 14)    -- 18
  ,('someone', now(), 13)    -- 19
  ,('someone', now(), 19)    -- 20
  ,('someone', now(), 20);   -- 21


-- Create a revision snapsnot
select create_revision_snapshot(13);

-- This query is meant to be faster ...
select * from revision_tree_perf(21);

-- ... than this one
select * from revision_tree(21);
```

The above example

```
select create_revision_snapshot(13);
select * from revision_tree_perf(21);
```

is meant to yield a record set that denotes the path from 21 to the root, i.e. `(21, 20, 19, 13, 12, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1)`. Part of the solution is taken by walking the tree (21 to 13, as there's a snapshot for 13, so there's no need to walk the tree any further) and by using the already 'cached' path from 13 to the root (taken from revision_snapshot). Hope that makes it a bit easier to understand...

Update:
I've come up with a potential improvement. This is just a stab in the dark, but I can imagine that `exists` clauses are quite expensive. I now marked the existence of a snapshot in the revision table:

```
CREATE TABLE revision (
  id serial primary key,
  parent_revision_id int references revision(id),
  username varchar(128),
  has_snapshot boolean default false,
  ts timestamp without time zone
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_revision_snapshot(_rev int) RETURNS void AS $func$
  DELETE FROM revision_snapshot WHERE revision_id=$1;
  INSERT INTO revision_snapshot (revision_id, parent_revision_id, depth) 
    (SELECT $1, id, depth FROM revision_tree($1));
  -- Mark revision table to avoid costly exists/in clause
  UPDATE revision SET has_snapshot = true WHERE id=$1;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

This changes the CTE part of the `revision_tree_perf` SP to

```
WITH RECURSIVE rev_list(id, parent_revision_id, depth) AS (
  SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, 1 -- AS depth
  FROM   revision t
  WHERE  t.id = $1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, r.depth + 1
  FROM   rev_list r
  JOIN   revision t ON t.id = r.parent_revision_id
  WHERE  t.has_snapshot = false
)
SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, t.depth FROM   rev_list t ORDER BY t.id;
```

This should execute quite quickly. The other part of the puzzle would be to return the content of revision_snapshot from the revision id where `has_snapshot=true` and join these two results. The problem is how to get this revision id from the CTE. I could store the query result of the CTE in a temp table and query for the revision id, or perhaps it's advisable not to write a CTE and write it as a loop instead. This way, one could keep track of the revision id at which the loop would exit (when `has_snapshot = true`). But I'm not sure how this would compare against a CTE.

What do people think about this approach?

Comment: Excellent question with the correct amount of DDL. BTW: the VALUES thingy accepts a comma list, too.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the comma list (it's been suggested in the other thread this one is based on), but I liked the verbose way better to play with it.

Comment: If tree for the “19” had been requested, should system also make sure subtrees for, say, “12” and “3” are also cached?

Comment: BTW: don't think your question is beeing ignored. It is just a hard question, harder than the rest. I'll look into it this weekend. (and a lot of others will, too. Trust me ...)

Comment: @vyegorov: Not necessarily. The cached values should only be considered when they exist. If no snapshot entry exists, the path needs to be explored by the recursive CTE. If however a snapshot exists along the path, it should be utilised (in your example for a requested "19", only 19 will be taken from the tree and the rest of the path gets assembled by the snapshot lookup which contains a path from "13" (assuming it contains one)). I added an explanation to the example, please see if it needs any more prose.

Comment: Cheers wildplasser. I figured it would be quite a brainteaser, and also hanks for taking a crack at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **completely revised version**.
In my minimal test, the new function using the `revision_snapshot` is actually faster now.
I made numerous changes. Most importantly:

- Don't add column to original table. That may speed up the query marginally, but it also introduces cost and overhead in the main table. May pay if all you ever do with the table is executing this function, but in real life, that's just one of many tasks.
- Remove temporary table from function. Can be done much cheaper with just the CTE.
- Fix `ORDER BY`, which was wrong.
- For more, read the **comments** in the code.

Also as [->sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/40d89/2) to play with.

```
CREATE TABLE revision (
  revision_id serial PRIMARY KEY -- Don't use useless name "id", that's an anti-pattern of ORMs
 ,parent_revision_id int  NOT NULL REFERENCES revision(revision_id) DEFERRABLE
  -- must be DEFERRABLE for self-reference of root
 ,ts timestamp  NOT NULL -- all columns NOT NULL 
 ,has_snapshot boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE -- columns ordered for perfect packing and performance
 ,username text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE revision_snapshot (
  depth int PRIMARY KEY
 ,revision_id int
);  -- simplified

-- Recursively return path from '_revision_id' to root
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION revision_tree(_revision_id int)
  RETURNS TABLE(depth int, revision_id int) AS
$func$
   WITH RECURSIVE l AS (
      SELECT 1::int AS depth, r.parent_revision_id AS revision_id
      FROM   revision r
      WHERE  r.revision_id = $1

      UNION ALL
      SELECT l.depth + 1, r.parent_revision_id  -- AS revision_id
      FROM   l
      JOIN   revision r USING (revision_id)
      WHERE  r.parent_revision_id <> 0
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM   l
   ORDER  BY l.depth; -- NOT revision_id!
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_revision_snapshot(_revision_id int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
   -- for tiny tables, DELETE is faster than TRUNCATE
   DELETE FROM revision_snapshot;

   INSERT INTO revision_snapshot (depth, revision_id) 
   SELECT depth, revision_id
   FROM   revision_tree($1);
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;


-- Faster version of 'revision_tree'.
-- Stops recursion as soon as  revision_snapshot covers the "last mile" to root
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION revision_tree_perf(_revision_id int)
  RETURNS TABLE(revision_id int) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY  -- works without expensive temp table
   WITH RECURSIVE l AS (
      SELECT 1::int AS depth, r.parent_revision_id AS revision_id  -- trim cruft, only two columns needed
      FROM   revision r
      WHERE  r.revision_id = $1

      UNION ALL
      SELECT l.depth + 1, r.parent_revision_id  -- AS revision_id
      FROM   l
      JOIN   revision r USING (revision_id)
      WHERE  r.parent_revision_id <> 0  -- stop condition needed, since parent_revision_id IS NOT NULL
      AND    NOT EXISTS (  -- NOT EXISTS faster than IN (SELECT...)
         SELECT 1 FROM revision_snapshot s WHERE s.revision_id = l.revision_id)
      )
   (  -- extra parens needed for separate ORDER BY in UNION ALL
   SELECT l.revision_id
   FROM   l
   ORDER  BY l.depth  -- NOT revision_id! Bug just didn't show because the test ids were ordered.
   )
   UNION ALL  -- NOT: UNION - correct and faster
   (
   SELECT s.revision_id
   FROM   revision_snapshot s
   WHERE  s.depth > (
      SELECT s0.depth
      FROM   revision_snapshot s0
      JOIN   l USING (revision_id)
      )  -- must be exactly 1 value - follows logically from CTE
   ORDER  BY s.depth
   );
END  -- no ; needed here
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; -- DO NOT quote language name!

-- Example tree
--
--                                                      +-- <10>
--                                                     /
--                              +- <4> -- <8> -- <9> -+- <11> -- <15> -- <16> -- <17>
--                             /                                    
--  <0> -- <1> -- <2> -- <3> -+
--                             \                                    
--                              +- <5> -- <6> -- <7> -- <12> -+- <14> -- <18>
--                                                             \
--                                                              \
--                                                               \
--                                                                \
--                                                                 +- <13> -- <19> -- <20> -- <21>
--

INSERT INTO revision (revision_id, username, ts, parent_revision_id) VALUES
   (0, 'root',    now(), 0)  -- referencing itself
  ,(1, 'someone', now(), 0)
  ,(2, 'someone', now(), 1)
  ,(3, 'someone', now(), 2)
  ,(4, 'someone', now(), 3)
  ,(5, 'someone', now(), 3)
  ,(6, 'someone', now(), 5)
  ,(7, 'someone', now(), 6)
  ,(8, 'someone', now(), 4)
  ,(9, 'someone', now(), 8)
  ,(10,'someone', now(), 9)
  ,(11,'someone', now(), 9)
  ,(12,'someone', now(), 7)
  ,(13,'someone', now(), 12)
  ,(14,'someone', now(), 12)
  ,(15,'someone', now(), 11)
  ,(16,'someone', now(), 15)
  ,(17,'someone', now(), 16)
  ,(18,'someone', now(), 14)
  ,(19,'someone', now(), 13)
  ,(20,'someone', now(), 19)
  ,(21,'someone', now(), 20);

ANALYZE revision; 

-- Create a revision snapsnot
select create_revision_snapshot(13);

ANALYZE revision_snapshot;
```

Call:

This query should be faster now:

```
SELECT * FROM revision_tree_perf(21);
```

.. than this one:

```
SELECT * FROM revision_tree(21);
```

Comment: Thanks for the **completely revised version**. It runs nicely and the performance improvement of the snapshot is very well noticeable. The only thing that puzzles me is the last part of the function (i.e. the part after `UNION ALL`). You select all entries of the snapshot table with higher depth than ... what? First of all, wouldn't it be smaller depth since you're looking at the end that's closer to the root (as opposed to the recursive bit that's farther away and already retrieved). Would you care to elaborate? I'm not refuting your answer, I just like to understand it a bit more...

Answer (score 0):

[this is not an answer; unfortunately my naive view is a lot **slower** than the materialized version in the OQ ;-]

here is a snippet to increase the population of the revision table a bit (after the 21 VALUES have been inserted, obviously) :

```
        -- clone the revision-table to make it larger
INSERT INTO revision (username, ts, parent_revision_id)
SELECT 'user' || src.id || 'clone' ||gs
        , src.ts+ gs*'1 min'::interval
        , src.parent_revision_id+ (21*gs)
FROM revision src
JOIN generate_series(1,10000) gs ON 1=1
        ;
-- SELECT * FROM revision;

VACUUM ANALYZE revision;
```

UPDATE:

I managed to create my own versions of the functions, which appear to be slightly faster than the originals (even if called before the originals)

```
DROP FUNCTION fnc_naive(_me INTEGER);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_naive(_me INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE(fixed int, this int, ancestor int, depth int) AS $body$
    WITH RECURSIVE tree(fixed, this, some_ancestor, the_level) AS (
      SELECT t.id AS fixed, t.id AS this
        , t.parent_revision_id AS some_ancestor, 1 AS the_level
      FROM   revision t
      WHERE  t.id = $1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT tr.fixed AS fixed, rev.id AS this
        , rev.parent_revision_id AS some_ancestor
        , tr.the_level+1 AS the_level
      FROM   tree tr
      JOIN   revision rev ON rev.id = tr.some_ancestor
   )
   SELECT t.fixed, t.this, t.some_ancestor, t.the_level
        FROM   tree t
        ORDER  BY t.this
        ;
$body$ LANGUAGE sql;

-- Altered "Fast" version of 'revision_tree' (to be). This version will return the 
-- revision tree making use of snapshots (recursively returning the path from 
-- specified revision id to last snapshot of the path to the root + the snapshot)
-- Changes:
--      replaced the IN(subselect) by a corresponding EXISTS (subselect)
--      Replaced the = (select(min() subselect) by the corresponding NOT EXISTS
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION revision_tree_perf_wp(_rev int)
RETURNS TABLE(parent_revision_id int) AS
$$
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_graph_result_wp ON COMMIT DROP AS
  WITH RECURSIVE rev_list(id, parent_revision_id, depth) AS (
      SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, 1
      FROM   revision t
      WHERE  t.id = $1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, r.depth + 1
      FROM   rev_list r
      JOIN   revision t ON t.id = r.parent_revision_id
      WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM revision_snapshot nx
                WHERE t.id = nx.revision_id
                )
        )
   SELECT t.id, t.parent_revision_id, t.depth
   FROM   rev_list t
        ;
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT g.parent_revision_id FROM tmp_graph_result_wp AS g
    WHERE g.parent_revision_id IS NOT NULL
   UNION
   SELECT s.parent_revision_id FROM revision_snapshot AS s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
          FROM tmp_graph_result_wp nx
          WHERE nx.parent_revision_id < s.revision_id
          )
   ORDER BY parent_revision_id
        ;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Additional notes: I do not understand the (intended) usage of the "revision_snapshot" and table and the temp table "graph_result". To me it appears that the naive treewalk will *always* be executed , plus an additional "exists in temp and/or cache tables) In any case: the naive version is considerably faster than the "cached" one.

Comment: Thanks. The intended usage of "revision_snapshot" is to bound the execution time of the tree walk to up unti a revision in "revision_snapshot" is found. With increasing depth of the tree, the execution time will increase (i.e. a walk from the requested node to the root). So the idea is to limit the walk and rely on the "cached" path in "revision_snapshot". In essence, the result should be the union of `{Path from requested node until last snapshot revision on path (call it 'n')} UNION {select * from revision_snapshot where revision_id=n}`. Thanks for the `EXISTS` thingy.

Comment: The naive version is only faster as the test data set is fairly small. It will hit a limitation eventually as I am sure postgres has some maximum recursion depth (MS SQL Server does). Also, scalability is an issue when it big trees have to be explored (long paths take longer than short ones; with a snapshot, this can be controlled to some extent).

Comment: No, there is no maximun recursion depth for recursive CTE's. They are excuted by iteration, not by recursion. (There is a maximum recursion depth for triggers etc, but that is a different issue)

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know that CTE recursion is unbounded. However, my point still stands that deep trees take long to explore. I'll run your table population script and see at which point it's faster to use the snapshot as opposed to exploring the tree.

Comment: I did a bit of performance testing by deepening the tree (`INSERT INTO revision (username, ts, parent_revision_id) SELECT 'user', now(), s.a FROM generate_series(21, 1000000) as s(a);`). If I query for the 900,000th element using the naive, recursive query, I obtain a result within 4s. Doing the same thing with a snapshot at 850,000 and the 'performant' query (leaving only 50,000 elements to retrieve from the CTE) is running for more than 5 minutes (terminated before it could finish). Returning the 850,000 snapshot records takes only a few 100ms, so something else must take so much time...